# Get total from a month and limit results MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to make a query that returns the top ten from a month. I hope this is possible directly through MySQL.

Basically I get some data every day (around 150 rows), with some information about different youtubers.
Each row has an Identifier, a Date, the YouTuber, and the number of views the youtuber got that day. It looks like this:

```
ID|Date|Youtuber|Views
126|2013-01-28|example|482612
```

I need to sum all of the views and to a total, for a month. For example May, and then i need to get the results that has most views for that month.

How would I do that through mysql? Or would I need to use php as well? :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT Youtuber, SUM(Views) as viewTotal FROM <TABLE> WHERE month(Date) = 5 GROUP BY Youtuber ORDER BY viewTotal LIMIT 0,10`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, this is allowed in MySQL.

Comment: Modifying yours a little made it work :D

SELECT Youtuber, SUM(Views) FROM <TABLE> WHERE month(Date) = 5 group by YouTuber ORDER BY Views DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Chill hd1, StackOverview told me to wait

Comment: `WHERE MONTH(Date)` cannot make use of an index on `date`, if such an index exists. Prefer a `WHERE date > ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT youtuber, SUM(views) AS total_views
FROM yourtable
WHERE date >= '2013-05-01' AND date < '2013-06-01'
GROUP BY youtuber
ORDER BY total_views DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two these as two queries:

1. Sum all of the views for a month. For example May.

   ```
   SELECT SUM(Views) as TotalViews 
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Date >= '2013-05-01' AND Date < '2013-06-01';
   ```
2. Get the results that has most views for that month.

   ```
   SELECT t.YouTuber, t.Date, t.Views
   From MyTable AS t
   JOIN (
       SELECT YouTuber, MAX(Views) AS Views
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE Date >= '2013-05-01' AND Date < '2013-06-01'
       GROUP BY YouTuber
     ) AS max USING (YouTuber, Views) 
   WHERE Date >= '2013-05-01' AND Date < '2013-06-01';
   ```